# Matplotlib code not executing due to labels?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm using the salem_executions_data.csv, this is how it looks like:

```
year,month,accusations,executions
1962,1,0,0
1962,2,3,0
1962,3,4,0
1962,4,22,0
1962,5,39,0
1962,6,3,1
1962,7,12,5
1962,8,23,5
1962,9,33,9
1962,10,1,0
1962,11,3,0
1962,12,0,0
1963,1,0,0
1963,2,0,0
1963,3,0,0
```

Working with Python 2.7, what I wanted was to:

- Load the csv file
- Make a accusations vs executions using 3d scatter

And what I have so far is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('data/salem_executions_data.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    from itertools import islice

    for row in islice(plots,1,None):

        for row in plots:
            temp=row[int(str(2))]
            x.append(temp)
            temp=row[int(str(3))]
            y.append(temp)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Accusations')
plt.ylabel('Executions')
plt.title('Accusations vs Executions')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Once I execute this cells I get no output code... Any help?

After adding %matplotlib inline this is the output I get, do you think its okay?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vsBj.jpg)

Update v3:

After changing plt.plot to plt.scatter:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGCS1.jpg)

Comment: If you don't get any error, the code runs fine. What's the problem then? Where/How do you run the code?

Comment: Sorry what I meant is that my notebook is not giving me the output.

Comment: You probably didn't tell the notebook how to output anything. Usually people use either `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook`. You may also use `%matplotlib tk` or `%matplotlib qt`.

Comment: It says /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:545: UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. "

Comment: If you want a scatter plot instead of a line plot, you probably want to call `plt.scatter(x,y)` instead of `plt.plot(x,y)`. You may want to sort your x,y points.

Comment: But you do get the plot shown, right? That warning tells you that there are no labelled objects in your graph. So you would either set a `label` to the `plot`, or you supply a list of `labels` to `legend`.

Comment: I suspect the "no labelled objects" problem is the result of calling `plt.legend()`.  There are no *data* labels.  Either remove that call, or change the plot function to something like `plt.plot(x, y, label='Something interesting here')`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys! Got what I wanted (updates at the end of the post) :)

Comment: I think you would still want to convert your data to numbers before plotting. `temp=int(row[2])` and `temp=int(row[3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I get a scatter. I have not changed anything from your code.  The only change i have made is to make it a scatter plot by replacing your code `plt.plot(x,y)` with `plt.plot(x,y,'.')`